# Handle file conflicts last while transferring data. (+rename automatically)

Tags: files, filemanager, transfer

Let's assume I want to copy or move many files from my mobile phone to the PC overnight.

I go to bed and wake up next morning, just to read a message that states “Error while copying ……… – libmtp error:  Could not get file from device.”, that came at 3% and halted the file transfer. So one tiny fault delayed the entire progress (the other 97%) of the file copying.

It would be better if it could first copy all files that **can be copied,** and then handle file conflicts (existing filename, unsupported characters for target file system, other errors) last, so that it can first get all the work done and **then** handle the faults.

It would also be good if I could tell the file copier **in advance** to rename existing files automatically, so that I do not have to wait for the file copier to encounter these files so I can tell it to rename files automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the default file manager in Ubuntu:

1. Right-click the folder containing the files on your phone you want to transfer to your PC, then click *Open in Terminal*.
2. Run one of these two commands (copy or move), replacing `<target>` with the destination path:

```
cp -r --backup=numbered * <target>
mv -r --backup=numbered * <target>
```

This will rename the target file with a `.~1~` suffix if there is a file name conflict. If a file ending with `.~1~` exists, `.~2~` is used, and so on.

Comment: I will try it out. I guess I have to use the bogus `mtp-fuse` when using MTP, in order to simulate a normal file system. But thanks alot, and welcome to StackExchange. Don't get intimidated if you get yelled at, that's normal on StackExchange and I had to deal with it alot.